# PHP json encode

Tags: php, json

Есть проблема необходимо привести текст в человеческий вид.

```html
<?php 
//$json='\u0414\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430';

//echo json_unescaped_unicode($json);
//echo json_encode($json,  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$ar = ["\u0414\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430 \u0410\u043d\u0433\u0435\u043b\u0430\u2192 \u0414\u0438\u0435\u0442"];
echo json_encode($ar,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


//echo (JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE($json));



  ?>
```

Выглядит он так (\u0414\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430 \u0410\u043d\u0433\u0435\u043b\u0430\u2192 \u0414\u0438\u0435\u0442).
Пробовал решать через JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE не работает. Однако данный декодер справился. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

А я бы сделал так

```
html_entity_decode(str_replace('\u','&#x',$ar[0]), ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode('"' . $ar[0] . '"');
```